# What are the implications of claiming space heritage if you don't have it?

Tags: testing, spacecraft-development, regulatory, procedure, qualification-testing

What would be the legal implications if a Company have claimed they have Spaceflight heritage for it's products, but the heritage was for the previous Company, which the owner shut it for legal reasons, they then copied and rebranded and are now selling with claimed heritage for the newco.
I believe it doesn't have heritage, but I am seeing this with a number of parts at present from a European Space start up, but not sure whether they can claim flight heritage?

Comment: If you actively lie it is boring old fraud. https://www.nasa.gov/news-release/nasa-investigation-uncovers-cause-of-two-science-mission-launch-failures/ If you are claiming your parts/hardware are 'related' you may be able to skate through. There is nothing special legally in 'space heritage', just normal business law and due diligence. A smart buyer would be ignoring the 'heritage' words and wanting to see documentation proving the part does what they want, evidence it flew before is nice but it might have got lucky then and you want to know it will always work for you.

Comment: @GremlinWranger Your link isn't about heritage, but about falsified technical documentation. Mangers worry about "heritage", engineers worry about "do we understand the details well enough to be sure this will work". If the specs don't meet the real, physical, mission requirements, you're in trouble regardless of "heritage". But if they do meet the requirements robustly, "heritage" is not a major engineering concern.

Comment: I'm confused about the scenario. As an engineer I don't care about what happened to the company or its branding. Are the parts the same ones, with a certain design and process for that design? If they engineer/manufacture their parts and they're trying to sell us new ones, are the engineers/machinists/etc the same?

Comment: Agree with @ErinAnne.  On a technical pov as long as you have sufficient evidence that they are the same parts (e.g. its test envelope results), I don't see a problem. Unless of course, the reason for the original company closing is due to said parts themselves.

Comment: Related scenario: A newly established company buys the blueprints for a flight-proven product and manufactures it under license, claiming space heritage. I don't think you can accuse them of fraud.

Comment: The parts are now from an old design which has flown as an In Orbit Demonstrator, however these were made and assembled in Europe and so went through testing, they are now being made in Asia, I don't know to what level they are being tested as they have been bought on price to turn a profit. My concern is that they fail as we are not comparing like for like.

Comment: But outer housings are new design, so in theory they are a new untested design anyway.

Comment: My belief is the Sales/Management are not being truthful to the customer, and believe they are buying a fully tested full technically proven part. My opinion is if they were built exactly to previous specification, these would be acceptable, but I know they are being purchased for less than the cost of the original BOM and inflation means there is no way component costs are now less than they were 3 years ago.

Comment: +1 good question. Everyone has made good points here. One aspect separating the comments into two camps is that whilst the Rainer P. example company can legitmately manufacture under licence they may not have "design authority". This would be really important if the customer wants support to understand (say) handling instructions/limits of qualification/ground test anomalies/you name it. If the vendor has no staff for engineering support then they may have an unhappy customer even before launch.

Comment: However this isn't just a risk for "newco". An original manufacturer might also lose lots of staff on an on-going product; it can happen at anytime in the companies lifetime if they simply mismanage looking after their staff. On the other side of the coin a sensible licensing manufacturer can choose to only go ahead with the transaction if they have enough voluntary key staff transfers. Business can be a minefield.

Comment: Getting back to the OP, park the word "heritage" for a moment, is the "newco" vendor truthfully claiming they have oldco staff on board and being straight about how they have acquired the design?  They could be being honest but just hope that no-one asks detailed questions. So much marketing goes right to the edge of borderline fraud, just look at how the original oldco were probably going about attracting finance for their start-up.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of ways that claims are made. When a scientist writes an abstract for a paper, the abstract will generally "make claims" that will hopefully be substantiated later in the paper. When you promote a company to investors, you may also make claims about what your company can or will try to do. If you read a datasheet for a product, that data sheet "makes claims" about what the product can do too. Claims are statements, and some are more rigorous than others, depending on the context and what people's expectations typically are.

When a claim is particularly nebulous, such as "we have spaceflight heritage", then someone who hears that claim will become informed that there's something (or some aspect) of *potential* value. They *may* want to inquire further if they think that a certain level of "spaceflight heritage" would add value in some way.

A company can make such a claim even if there is a very tenuous connection to some kind of space heritage. It's up to the recipient of the claim to ask more focused clarifying questions. Trust, but verify.

For example, if someone claims "space heritage" you could ask, "Does this mean that you have a [TRL9-level](https://www.nasa.gov/directorates/somd/space-communications-navigation-program/technology-readiness-levels/#:%7E:text=Technology%20Readiness%20Levels%20(TRL)%20are,based%20on%20the%20projects%20progress.) product?".

Or, you could simply ask, "Is this specific product flight-proven?"

Another way to look at...

When a company makes a claim, it's like they are opening the door for you to engage with them. They're saying, "This is what we believe, and if you are willing to take the time to learn more, we think that you will also come to believe the same thing." The claims *permit you to ask more direct questions*, and in the process explore the possibility of forming a business relationship with them.